# Transparency fade-in transition on background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a fade in transparency effect on my website's header. Right now the effect is backwards. How could i possibly reverse it ?

[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qoc6bbnm/1/)

Also, the transparency effect should be only on the image, not the text.

This is my code right now:

```
#header ul li a:hover{
   color:#FF4242;
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/CJub1gt.png?1?7924) no-repeat 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: You can't use opacity on a background image.

Comment: @Paulie_D i know , but im sure there is a workaround to achieve what im trying to do , with a different approach

Comment: Yep, you'd need to use a pseudo-element positioned correctly with the image as a background on that...and then use opacity on the pseudo element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra div to the li element and use as background with animation: http://jsfiddle.net/qoc6bbnm/3/

```
<li><a href="">Home</a><div class="back"></div></li>
```

the new css values (remove #header ul li a and #header ul li a:hover)

```
#header ul li a:hover{
    color:#FF4242;
}

#header ul li {
    position:relative;
}

#header ul li div.back{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    color:#FF4242;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/CJub1gt.png?1?7924) no-repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    opacity: 0
}

#header ul li:hover div.back{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , can i ask what does `position:relative;` achieve here ?

Comment: Well, i always use position:relative to the element that has a inner element with position:absolute, but in this case, if you want, you can remove it because there is not LEFT, RIGHT, TOP or BOTTOM propriety for .back div

Comment: on my original website, header has an image in the background already, and that causes your solution not work :/

Comment: i updated my jsfiddle to show you the situation.. http://jsfiddle.net/qoc6bbnm/8/

Comment: just remove the z-index:-1; from .back and add position:relative and z-index:1 to a elemen, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qoc6bbnm/9/

Comment: i really appreciate your answer and help :) thanks a lot, sorry for the late reply it was 5:00am

Comment: Well, i'm italian. For me, it was 9:00pm :)